# How can I ask a parachain which relay it is connected to?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

I can get a parachain's name and a parachain's id from the RPC system calls, but how can I get it to hint at which relay chain it is connected to? (The genesis hash of the relay would do)

Answer (score 2):

Not maybe a direct answer, but if you discover the parachains via the relay chain then you know which relay chain they are associated with.

Comment: True! You can also get this info through sidecar's endpoint `/paras` which lists all registered paras (parathreads & parachains) of the relay chain you are connected to. Example from the public sidecar https://kusama-public-sidecar.parity-chains.parity.io/paras/